# Where can I queue for Ashran?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have a PvP Quest to acquire 100 Artifact Shards from Ashran. I am aware this is a PvP battleground of sorts, but it's also a major city hub (Warspear / Stormshield), and while I've been to the latter fairly often over the 90-100 journey, I've never been to the former.

Attempting to leave the faction city appears to bring me into a queue once I reach the main part of the island, but is there any other way? Ashran does not appear to be an option under the battleground menu like other PvP content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to queue for ashran, you must go to warspear/stormshield and remain in that town until you are accepted into the queue. Usually the queue is fairly short, and you could farm artifacts in pve while you wait outside the city on the beach (this may have been removed, they seemed to be not dropping last I checked).

Comment: Actually, I don't believe you're required to stay in your respective faction hub. I was questing in Nagrand yesterday when my Ashran queue informed me I could now enter the battle.

Comment: You do not need to stay there, but you do need to go there to enter the Queue. They should really make it like Wintergrasp was, where you can enter the Queue, doesn't matter where you are.